# Display a variable's name along with output?

Tags: powershell

Sometimes when I'm writing a script I want to dump the value of a bunch of variables in my script to the console along with the variable's name.

Instead of having to do "var1: $var1" for all of my variables is there a powershellism that can display a bunch of variables along with their names? Is there some kind of convenient reflectiony thing for this?

Comment: So fresh and so clean :) c'mon make it an answer ! This will help many - this question is really nice too

Comment: This should be an answer. Funny, now I remember reading about the get-variable cmdlet a long time ago and wondering when such a thing would be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Get-Variable` cmdlet, which return `PSVariable` objects to you. By default, them formatted as table with two columns: `Name` and `Value`.